# How really works cycles and multiple cascade paths in EF Core

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

Could someone explain me why I have this error.

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_CommentMention_User_UserId' on
>   table 'CommentMention' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.

```
public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset CreationDate { get; set; } = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

    public int? CandidatureId { get; set; }
    public Candidature Candidature { get; set; }

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public User Author { get; set; }

    public IList<CommentMention> MentionedUsers { get; set; } = new List<CommentMention>();
}

public class CommentMention
{
    public int CommentId { get; set; }
    public Comment Comment{ get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; } // That's the foreign property which cause the error
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Role { get; set; }

    public bool Disabled { get; set; } = false;

    public DateTimeOffset CreationDate { get; set; } = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

    public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }

    public int? CreatedByUserId { get; set; }
    public User CreatedByUser { get; set; }

    public IList<User> SubUsers { get; set; } = new List<User>();

    [InverseProperty("CreatedByUser")]
    public IList<Candidature> CreatedCandidatures { get; set; } = new List<Candidature>();

    [InverseProperty("Lawyer")]
    public IList<Candidature> LawyerCandidatures { get; set; } = new List<Candidature>();

    [InverseProperty("Agent")]
    public IList<Candidature> AgentCandidatures { get; set; } = new List<Candidature>();

    public IList<UserDocument> Documents { get; set; } = new List<UserDocument>();

    public IList<Comment> Comments { get; set; } = new List<Comment>();

    public IList<Event> Events { get; set; } = new List<Event>();

    public IList<Reminder> Reminders { get; set; } = new List<Reminder>();

    public IList<CommentMention> Mentions { get; set; } = new List<CommentMention>();

    [InverseProperty("Owner")]
    public IList<Notification> Notifications { get; set; } = new List<Notification>();

    [NotMapped]
    public string FullName => this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName;
}
```

Actually the question is NOT HOW TO FIX IT, because I already know the soltuion which is to add restricted deletion behavior.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CommentMention>()
    .HasOne(x => x.User)
    .WithMany(x => x.Mentions)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

The real question is where is those 'cycles or multiple cascade paths' because I don't see which would cause that error.

Let's cover the possible deletion variants:

1. A record in CommentMention is deleted: no cascade deletion because
   that's child/dependent entity.
2. A record in Comment is deleted: cascade deletion of releted records
   in CommentMention.
3. A record in User is deleted: cascade deletion of releated records in
   Candidature, UserDocument, Comment, Event, Reminder,
   **CommentMention** and Notification tables.

Also I'm wondering is there a different between cycles and multiple since there is 'or' keyword between them which means thats two possible cascade paths.

Diagram of those tables: [image: diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you delete a user. This causes you to delete *their* `CommentMentions` via the `userID` in the table.

But it also causes you to delete the comments that they authored, which in turn means we have to delete `CommentMentions` via the `CommentId`.

Two *different* cascade paths that lead to attempts to delete in `CommentMentions`.

There isn't a cycle for this. You're correct. SQL Server uses one message to cover two different scenarios, but there may also be scenarios where both parts of the message *do* apply.

You'd have a cycle for the `CreatedByUserId` foreign key if you tried to enforce cascading deletes for it.

---

It may be most easily seen by looking at the diagram. Pick a direction to chase foreign keys in - either always towards the key or always towards the... other end<sup>1</sup>.

If you can find two different routes between two tables using any of those FKs, then you potentially has multiple cascade paths so you can't have cascading deletes on *all* of the FKs in those paths. If you can find a route back to the same table, you potentially have cycles so you can't have cascading deletes on *all* of the FKs on that path.

---

<sup>1</sup>I've never figured out what the other end of those lines is meant to represent. Is it meant to be a link from a chain? An infinity symbol? Something else?